# Run QML in Beaglebone Black

Tags: qt, qml, beagleboneblack

I built an image for Beaglebone Black based on the following instructions:
[build image for BBB](https://forum.digikey.com/t/debian-getting-started-with-the-beaglebone-black/12967).
After that, I have crosscompiled Qt 5 for BBB based on this instructions:
[crosscompiled Qt for BBB](https://github.com/K3tan/BBB_QT5_guide).
I have created and compiled a Qt quick application to run on board BBB but I got the this error:
[image]

How to fix this error?

Here is the Qt Quick and Qt QML in config.summary file: 
Qt QML: 
QML network support .................... yes 
QML debugging and profiling support .... yes 
QML sequence object .................... yes 
QML list model ......................... yes 
QML XML http request ................... yes 
QML Locale ............................. yes 
QML delegate model ..................... yes 
Qt Quick: 
Direct3D 12 ............................ no 
AnimatedImage item ..................... yes 
Canvas item ............................ yes 
Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes 
Flipable item .......................... yes 
GridView item .......................... yes 
ListView item .......................... yes 
TableView item ......................... yes 
Path support ........................... yes 
PathView item .......................... yes 
Positioner items ....................... yes 
Repeater item .......................... yes 
ShaderEffect item ...................... yes 
Sprite item ............................ yes

Comment: You are missing many modules, check the configuration summary that everything required for QtQuick is found.
Anyway, that Debian version should have Qt 5 already available trough apt

Comment: It's important to note that your runtime environment needs to have the same modules in it as the build environment. Especially as cross-compiling means that they are on different machines. You need to deploy your dependencies like e.g. `apt install qml-module-qtquick2` etc. on the BBB. This lists some of those available https://packages.debian.org/source/bookworm/qtdeclarative-opensource-src

Comment: I installed all packages at https://packages.debian.org/source/bookworm/qtdeclarative-opensource-src on BBB but the problem has not been resolved.